# ¿Como pasar los datos de un ArrayList<String> a un Objeto?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

¿Como puedo pasar los datos que tengo en un `ArrayList<>` de tipo `String` a un objeto personalizado el cual luego pasa los datos a un adaptador?.

El problema que tengo es que como lo hago actualmente me genera nuevas instancias de los datos lo cual hace que cada vez que haga una consulta de los datos, en el `RecyclerView` se repitan los datos cada vez.

Así esta el código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        //Se recorre cada posición del Array
        try {

            JSONObject hijo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            ListaPadres.add(hijo.getString("cedula_padre"));

            ListaSpinner.add(hijo.getString("nombre_hijo"));

            //Aqui es donde se instancia cada vez que llega el objeto "RecibirEstudiantes" y 
            //le paso los datos, pero quisiera saber si hay otra forma de pasarle esos mismos 
            //datos para que no se repita la información.
            adapter.addMensaje(m = new RecibirEstudiantes(ListaSpinner.get(i),ListaPadres.get(i)));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Clase "RecibirEstudiantes":**

```
public class RecibirEstudiantes {
private String nombre;
private String cedula;

public RecibirEstudiantes() {
}

public RecibirEstudiantes(String nombre, String cedula) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.cedula = cedula;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getCedula() {
    return cedula;
}

public void setCedula(String cedula) {
    this.cedula = cedula;
}
}
```

**Esto es lo que busco, algo parecido a esto:**

```
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            try {
                //Se obtienen todas las conversaciones almacenadas en la base de datos de Firebase
                MensajeRecibir m = dataSnapshot.getValue(MensajeRecibir.class);
                //Cada mensaje que vaya recibiendo, este sera enviado al dapter
                adapter.addMensaje(m);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuando dices "me genera nuevas instancias de los datos" te refieres a `new RecibirEstudiantes` ó, cuando haces `get` de las listas

Comment: Te sugiero agregues que necesita el objeto RecibirEstudiantes para inicializar, en el código de tu pregunta lo inicializas con 2 objetos, me parece que en realidad necesita dos textos.

Comment: en cada iteracion del for estas crean un nuevo objeto de tu clase

Comment: Segun el titulo de la pregunta "¿Como pasar los datos de un ArrayList<String> a un Objeto?" mas cuando hace `hijo.getString` que me supongo que el metodo esta devolviendo un string, por lo que a `new RecibirEstudiantes` si le esta pasando dos cadenas. Adicional como dice @IgmerRodriguez en cada iteracion se crea un nuevo objecto.

Comment: A que te refiers con "no se repita la información" ????

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa si asi es, `new RecibirEstudiantes` se instancia cada vez que que el `For` hace una iteración, eso lo se perfectamente, la cuestión es que no se otro método o forma para que pueda pasar esos datos sin que se cree nuevamente una instancia. Al hacer la prueba en el teléfono, cada vez que hago la consulta se repite los datos y no se borran los anteriores.

Comment: @RosyecParrado RecibirEstudiantes() recibe dos cadenas u objetos?

Comment: @Jorgesys recibe dos cadenas, ya en un momento pongo el código de `RecibirEstudiantes`.

Comment: @RosyecParrado es que tu pregunta es bastante confusa, debiste comenzar con que quieres limpiar la informacion de `adapter` con cada busqueda. algo parecido a `adapter.clear()`, pero para eso debemos saber como esta contruida tu adapter.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa puede ser, pero antes de eso quería saber si había otra forma de pasar los datos en vez de simplemente borrar los del adapter.

Comment: Podrias hacer que por cada busqueda creas una nueva instancia de adapter.

Comment: Pregunta?, adapter es una variable que siempre esta viva o por cada busqueda la creas nuevas?

Comment: Siempre esta viva, la tengo declara antes de manera global.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86342/discussion-between-rosyec-parrado-and-orlando-de-la-rosa).

Answer (score 0):

Después de pensarlo un poco y gracias a la ayuda de **@Orlando De La Rosa**, dí con la solución de la siguiente manera:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
//Le paso nulo al recyclerView
AdapterEstudiantes a;
//Creo una nueva instancia del adaptador
a = new AdapterEstudiantes(getActivity);
//Le paso el nuevo adaptador al recyclerView
reyclerView.setAdapter(a);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
      a.addMensaje(m = new RecibirEstudiantes(ListaSpinner.get(i),ListaPadres.get(i)));
      //Le paso los datos al nuevo adaptador y LISTO!
    }
```

No pude encontrar otra manera es por eso como decía **@Orlando De La Rosa**, era mejor borrar los datos anteriores y volver a pasarlos.